# How to make drop down boxes appear when a specific value has been selected?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

So as it says above I have drop-down boxes that I want to appear in winforms C# when the value in the box matches the value of the previous drop-down. Here is an example but it does not work.

```
if (devicemodel.SelectedText == "iPod");
{
  Show.comboBox1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `comboBox1.Visible = false` on form load. Then:

```
if (devicemodel.Text == "iPod") 
{
  comboBox1.Visible=true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I am a noob to coding and only started a few days ago :) you really helped

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
comboBox1.Visible = true;
```